# Paginate query with multiple joins

Tags: php, mysql, join, pagination

I have query with few LEFT OUTER JOINS, as you can see in code i generate object that contains 2 objects populated with arrays, as you know i can't use "simple" pagination here because for one user i get few columns (for every role and every group) so for example for user 1 i can get 4-5 results because user can have many groups and roles and i understand that is main reason why i cant in this query use LIMIT and offset because i would lose some info. My question is, how to modify this query in way that i get 20 different users per page and ALL their roles and groups.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT u.id, u.firstName, u.lastName, u.email, 
    u.phoneNumber, u.address, u.birthDate, ur.roleName, cg.id, cg.name FROM users as u 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN user_role as ur ON u.id = ur.userId 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN user_group as ug on ug.userId = u.id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN control_group as cg on cg.id = ug.groupId WHERE u.id != ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_SESSION["id"]);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $firstName, $lastName, $email, $phoneNumber, 
    $address, $birthDate, $roleName, $groupId, $groupName);

$users = array();

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    if (empty($users[$id])) {
        $users[$id] = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'firstName' => $firstName,
            'lastName' => $lastName,
            'email' => $email,
            'phoneNumber' => $phoneNumber,
            'address' => $address,
            'birthDate' => $birthDate,
            'roles' => array(),
            'groups' => array()
        );
    }
    if ($roleName) {
        $found = false;
        foreach ($users[$id]['roles'] as $role) {
            if($role['roleName'] == $roleName){
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if($found == false)
            $users[$id]['roles'][] = array(
                'roleName' => $roleName
            );
     }

    if ($groupId) {
        $found = false;
        foreach ($users[$id]['groups'] as $group) {
            if($group['groupName'] == $groupName){
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if($found == false)
            $users[$id]['groups'][] = array(
                'groupName' => $groupName
            );
     }
}

$res = []; 

foreach($users as $user) { 
    $res[] = $user; 
} 

$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
echo json_encode($res);
```

Comment: You can get all the result in an array and then apply `arrayslice` with offset and length

Comment: What is point of that, still i will make get all on database, i want to get 20 users with their roles and groups.

Comment: it was just because you wrote "i cant in this query use LIMIT and offset because i would lose some info"? What does it mean

Comment: Are the tables related to `user` is having `one-to-one` association ? If yes then you can place the limit offset in the query, however the behaviour changes when the `user` table is associated with `one-to-many` and you can get multiple rows for the same user id, having said that the pagination query depends on how the relation among tables are defined.

Comment: User is related to roles and groups with many to many because user can have many roles and role can have many users. 
@NishantNair on this existing query i cant use LIMIT because for example when i execute this query i will get multiple results for one user, so if user have 2 groups and 2 roles i will get 4 results for one user, and on that way i can't use LIMIT because i wont get 20 different users correct ? and my questions here is how to modify this query to return me 20 different users per page and all their groups and roles.

Comment: Would splitting the single query in 2 queries be acceptable? Make the first query get just the User columns, this query you can paginate with a LIMIT. Then you foreach over that resultset, and run the second query that gets all the other data from the other tables, based on the userid from the first query result. Then you do your array merge much like you already do.

Comment: That is my last and desperate solution, because on that way i would have like 21 database call on each page, so 1 call to get all users on required page, and other calls for each user to get all groups and roles, so that is many many calls and i'm looking way to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think you could go for two queries approach.
With first one you do pagination

```
SELECT u.id FROM users LIMIT offset, count
```

and second one is one that you have with 
u.id = (I think it should be =, not != as you have) changed to u.id IN

Smth like that

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT u.id from users u limit ?, ?");
$stmt->bind_param("1", $_SESSION["offset"]);
$stmt->bind_param("2", $_SESSION["limit"]);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id);

$user_ids = array();

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $user_ids[] = $id;
}

$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT u.id, u.firstName, u.lastName, u.email, 
    u.phoneNumber, u.address, u.birthDate, ur.roleName, cg.id, cg.name FROM users as u 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN user_role as ur ON u.id = ur.userId 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN user_group as ug on ug.userId = u.id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN control_group as cg on cg.id = ug.groupId WHERE u.id in (?)");
$stmt2->bind_param("1", implode(",", user_ids);
$stmt2->execute();
$stmt2->bind_result($id, $firstName, $lastName, $email, $phoneNumber, 
    $address, $birthDate, $roleName, $groupId, $groupName);

$users = array();

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you please give me code example how i could achieve that ?

Comment: I will try this and will let you know if it helped me, thx for suggestion!

Comment: $stmt2->bind_param("1", implode(",", user_ids); that part is not working, any idea how i could bind array of ids ?

Comment: Yeah, I missed one closing bracket. but generally you bind a string (implode makes a sting out of array)